# How to activate the scroll in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll

I'm with problems configuring the scrollbar in a frame, where I have words that the users favor. Here's my class:

```
class Functions_favorite_section:
    def __init__(self, path, frame_favorite, fk):
        self.frame_favorite = frame_favorite
        self.path = path
        self.img = img.Images()
        self.fk = fk
        self.fm = fm.File_manager()
        self.favorite = []
        self.button_trash = []
        self.button_pencil = []
        self.trash = r"/Documentos/Speaker/aplication-tg/Img\delete.png"
        self.pencil = r"/Documentos/Speaker/aplication-tg/Img\Img\pencil.png"
        self.delimiter = ">/"
        self.x = 20
        self.y = 45
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.frame_favorite, orient="vertical")
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.frame = Canvas(self.frame_favorite, background="green")
        self.frame.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.frame.yview)
        self.frame.update()
        self.frame.config(scrollregion=self.frame.bbox("all"))
    #ok
    def add_favorite(self):

        text = self.fk.get_text()
        self.fm.edit_file(text+self.delimiter, self.path, 'a')
        self.control_favorite()


    def edit_favorite(self, text):
        self.fk.print_value(text)


    def delete_favorite(self, text):
        
        self.fm.delete_sentence(text, self.path)
        self.control_favorite()

    def show_favorite(self):
        for index, favorite in enumerate(self.fm.get_sentence(self.path)):
            if favorite !='':
                label = Label(self.frame_favorite, text=favorite, font=("Arial", 18), highlightbackground="yellow", background="yellow", width=15, anchor="w")
                label.place(x=self.x, y=self.y + 5)
                label.bind("label", '<Button-1>', lambda event: self.fk.print_value(label))
                self.favorite.append(label)
                self.y += 80
                print(index, favorite)
                
        self.y = 30
        print(len(self.favorite))
    def show_trash(self):
        for index, favorite in enumerate(self.favorite):
            if favorite != '':
                self.button_trash.append(Button(self.frame_favorite, text="exclui",
                                                command=lambda i=index: self.delete_favorite(self.favorite[i].cget("text")), background="red",
                                                border=2,
                                                height=3, width=3))
                self.button_trash[index].place(x=self.x + 200, y=self.y + 10)
                self.y += 80
        self.y = 30


    def show_pencil(self):
        for index, favorite in enumerate(self.favorite):
            if favorite !='':
               self.button_pencil.append(Button(self.frame_favorite, text="edita",
                                               command=lambda i=index: self.delete_favorite(self.favorite[i].cget("text")), background="#07C7F2", border=2, height=3, width=3))
               self.button_pencil[index].place(x=self.x + 250, y=self.y + 10)
               self.y += 80
        self.y = 30

#image=self.img.load_image(self.pencil)
    def hide_trash(self):
        for item in self.button_trash:
            item.place_forget()

    def hide_pencil(self):
        for item in self.button_pencil:
            item.place_forget()

    def hide_favorite(self):
        for item in self.favorite:
            item.place_forget()
        self.favorite.clear()

    def hide_all(self):
        self.hide_favorite()
        self.hide_trash()
        self.hide_pencil()

    def control_favorite(self):
        try:
            self.hide_all()
        finally:
            self.show_favorite()
            self.show_trash()
            self.show_pencil()
```

I would like to know because it is happening. Is the frame correct?
The bar even appears, but it doesn't work. I searched on the Web, GPT, etc. Does somebody know the solution? Thanks. Help me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is far more code than is necessary to diagnose or reproduce whatever issue you may be having with a scrollbar. Pleas read [ask] and try to pare this down to a [mre]. And in the event that the code under "The class Interface" is still relevant to the issue, please format and indent it correctly.

Comment: Also, the code you've posted under "The class Instance_controller" is identical to the code posted under "the class Canvas_elements", which I assume is not intentional

Comment: You can't scroll the contents of a frame.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: A Canvas can only scroll items drawn on it by the various `.create_XXXX()` methods - I don't see you doing that anywhere in this code.  And any time you add or remove items, you have to update the `scrollregion` option - you're only doing that once, at a time when the Canvas is empty, so no scrolling will be available.

Comment: @jasonharper Could you rewrite the code please?